# Change default action for keys

Tags: android

I wrote small service class and I want implement something like that :
service start -> remap key event -> using my "hard coded" key events 
-> stopped -> back to normal key events...

Thanks for help :-)

Comment: Interesting. And your question is? *(in case it is "How to do that?" -> [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/))*

Comment: my question is could you give me some sugestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately, what you want is impossible, for obvious security reasons.